# html input change background on value not equal 0

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, input

This question has been asked before, however, after using many of the methods described I cannot get this to work.

I am trying to change the background of a div when a user focuses on an input box AND also when there is text inside, i.e. != 0.  I can get the focus to work, but blur is not functioning correctly.

jQuery:

```
$('.pI_nameText1').focus( function() {
   $(".nameLights").addClass("lightOverlay");
});
$('.pI_nameText1').blur( function() {
   $(".nameLights").removeClass('lightOverlay');
   if ( $(".pI_nameText1").val == '') {
       $('.nameLights').removeClass("lightOverlay");
   }
});
```

HTML:

```
<input id="comments" placeholder="Type many lines of texts in here and you will see magic stuff" class="pI_nameText1"></input>
<div class="nameLights"></div>
```

Here is a fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/3fnzL/

I believe that the problem may be related to how I have written the if statement...

Comment: You're always removing the same class, I don't get it ?

Comment: Is this it -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/3fnzL/1/

Comment: You mean you want the class to remain if the user has entered text?

Comment: Thanks Guys, James' answer below is what I was looking for.  The script adds the class on focus and removes when out of focus, but doesn't remove when the value != ermpty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the [proper answer](http://jsfiddle.net/3fnzL/3/). You should be using `.val()` instead of `.val`, and I also changed around the order of the if statement to make it more logical:

```
$('.pI_nameText1').blur( function() {
    if ($(".pI_nameText1").val() == '') {
        $(".nameLights").removeClass('lightOverlay')
    }
});
```

In the future, you should use `console.log();` for debugging. With `console.log($(".pI_nameText1").val)` it returned an object, not a string, which was a clear indicator of what the problem was. You can access the console in most browsers with F12, or by right clicking, choosing inspect element, and finding the console tab in the developer's window.

Comment: Thanks James, I knew it was something syntax related...I have seen console used before but not really known how...is there a reason why it simply returns "" when used as you have it?

Comment: @sventizzle `console.log()` returns whatever is in it to the console. Currently in the fiddle, it is returning the value of the textbox only if the value is equal to empty. If you move it outside of the `if` statement, it will print whatever is in the textbox on `.blur`. Any variable, string, or number can be returned through the console in this manner.